# Reading string from vector until whitespace in C++

Tags: c++

This is probably easy but im not sure how. I tried searching multiple websites and yes Google and couldn't find anything on this.

My vector `result[0]` looks like this

```
A3 * * B4 * *
```

Declaration

```
vector<string> result = v.formVectorFile("Prj3 Config.txt");
```

I know that `cin` reads until whitespace so I was trying to use this to figure it out.
If I read straight from `fstream` I can read until whitespace, but im trying to do this with a string inside a vector and something like `result[0] >> s;` obviously doesnt work.

I need to read until it hits a whitespace then read the next one until whitespace. Etc...
So extract `A3` by itself. Operate on it then extract `*` etc...

Comment: You need to show some code, what you've tried, etc.  There must be a ton of solutions out there for this problem.

Comment: At least show us the declaration of  `result` ?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Sorry, im not used to this. My attempts were pretty folly so I didnt bother posting them. I will take more heed next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear because you don't tell us precisely what `result` is.

If we can assume that `result` is a `std::vector<std::string>`, then you can do something like this:

```
std::istringstream iss(result[0]); // consider only first string in vector
std::string item;
while(iss >> item) {
  std::cout << "I found: " << item << "\n";
}
```

If we assume that `result` is `std::vector<char>`, then you can do this:

```
std::string s(result.begin(), result.end()); // consider entire vector as single string
std::istringstream iss(s);
while(iss >> item) {
  std::cout << "I found: " << item << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you rob. This was what I was trying to do exactly. Im new though and did not know about std::istringstream. Thank you.